# Take a look at this spam user

Tags: discussion, support, new-users, spam

A user looks like a spam account. First question asked by this user is not about any programming or any relevant problem but its just advertisement of its website and promote how they are better in this.

How do we stop this kind of mess on Stack Overflow?

Comment: Question was deleted just as I flagged it as spam. You can always flag questons like this yourself.

Comment: Downvote, flag as spam, move on. Only takes a minute or two and it is destroyed :)

Comment: Right. But Can we complain about this?

Comment: Sure, but there's no need. If they contribute spam, flag it as such. They will be stopped pretty soon. If you'd really like to, you could come tell us in [The Tavern](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta) if we didn't already catch it.

Comment: @Bart: I flagged your comment promoting The Tavern as spam. It contains too much self-promotion :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You don't need to do anything other than flag such posts as spam. The system takes care of it from there on out.

If a post gains 6 such flags from community members, the post itself will be deleted right there. If it takes a little longer, a moderator will come looking and deal with the spam, and will usually destroy the user account too (taking any other spam content down with it).

Your spam flags also feed into automated anti-spam measures training machine-learning algorithms to recognise the spammers; most spam is already dealt with automatically by that system:

[image: spam blocked graph]

([*source*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/237848/anti-spam-blocking-questions-whose-bodies-end-with-a-raw-hyperlink/237882))

There is no need to post about spam accounts here on Meta. The community runs a pattern-matching bot called the [SmokeDetector](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/wiki), reporting to [Charcoal HQ](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) (with reports being reposted to the [Tavern on the Meta](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), [SO close vote reviewers](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) and a [host of other chat rooms](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/wiki/Chat-Rooms) as needed); this bot looks out for the posts the system missed (as well as other low-quality issues across the Stack Exchange network). You could tell its operators about new spam if you think it won't get deleted quickly enough otherwise.

Comment: [The spam detecting bot no longer has a machine learning system.](https://github.com/Charcoal-SE/SmokeDetector/commit/68d49ccc0b4981a4ebe91d993f42643542e44d80)

Comment: @dorukayhan: duly updated.

Comment: @rene: added that too.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The bot is actually headquartered in [Charcoal HQ](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq) unresolved reports after a grace period will just also be posted to the tavern.

Comment: @Magisch: at this point I'm going: suggest me an edit to improve this answer :-D

Comment: @Magisch: there, I think I cover the bot better now.